# Want to add derived class object to base class list

Tags: c#, list, generics

kind of new to c#. Did research, found out can do it like it's done in java but not sure where i am wrong

```
namespace WcfService3
{    
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace WcfService3
{   
    public class Dog:Animal
    {
    }

}

List<Animal> listAnimal = new List<Animal>();

Dog obDog = new Dog();
obDog.Name = "Pluto";
listAnimal.Add(obDog );
```

Comment: All of that looks reasonable, what is going wrong?

Comment: it's just throwing error

Comment: Where is it throwing the error?

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: if i replace listAnimal.Add(obDog ) with listAnimal.Add(new Animal()); then it works fine

Comment: That should work too. What error *exactly* are you getting?

Comment: i am calling this function from javascript using ajax. it just go to error block

Comment: @user3653156 And you can't set a breakpoint? Log the error? Just saying "It doesn't work" is *ridiculously* hard to debug. Another idea, just throw this into a console app and play with it, then put it back into your real app.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry.. kind of new..I will do that

Comment: your code is working correctly the problem is for somewhere else, debug your problem.